# cascade = CascadeType.ALL not working is spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring, api, hibernate, jpa

I have two model as shown below:

1.

```
public class LaboratoryTransaction extends Transaction {

     @ManyToMany
     @JoinTable(name = "lab_txn_complaints_symptoms",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "lab_txn_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "symptom_id"))
     private Set<SymptomsDirectory> symptoms = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "lab_txn_provisional_diagnosis",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "lab_txn_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "dieases_id"))
    private Set<DiseaseDirectory> provisional_diagnosis = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "laboratoryTransaction", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private Set<LaboratoryTransactionDetail> laboratoryTransactionDetails = new HashSet<>();

    public LaboratoryTransaction addLabTnxDetail(LaboratoryTransactionDetail transaction) {
        laboratoryTransactionDetails.add(transaction);
        //transaction.setLaboratoryTransaction(this);
        return this;
    }

}
```

2. 

```
public class LaboratoryTransactionDetail extends Service {

     @JsonIgnore
     @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
     @JoinColumn(name = "laboratoryTransactionId)
     private LaboratoryTransaction laboratoryTransaction;

     @ManyToOne
     @JoinColumn(name = "packageId")
     private LabPackages labPackages;

     @JsonIgnore
     @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "laboratoryTransactionDetail")
     private Set<ExperimentReadings> experimentResultsByParameters = new HashSet<>();

    public LaboratoryTransactionDetail addExperimentReading(ExperimentReadings experimentReadings) {
         this.experimentResultsByParameters.add(experimentReadings);
         experimentReadings.setLaboratoryTransactionDetail(this);
         return this;
    }
}
```

I have an api call to accept json object via a post mapping

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class Laboratory {
    private LaboratoryInvestigationService laboratoryInvestigationService;
    private LaboratoryTransactionService laboratoryTransactionService;
    private InvestigationGroupService investigationGroupService;

    public Laboratory(LaboratoryInvestigationService laboratoryInvestigationService,
                      LaboratoryTransactionService laboratoryTransactionService,
                      InvestigationGroupService investigationGroupService) {
        this.laboratoryInvestigationService = laboratoryInvestigationService;
        this.laboratoryTransactionService = laboratoryTransactionService;
        this.investigationGroupService = investigationGroupService;
    }

    @PostMapping("lab/transactions/add")
    LaboratoryTransaction addLabTxn(@RequestBody LaboratoryTransactionCommand laboratoryTransactionCommand){

        laboratoryTransactionCommand.setDateTransaction(LocalDate.now());
        return laboratoryTransactionService.add(laboratoryTransactionCommand);
    }
}
```

In my service layer I implemented save as follows

```
@Component
public class LaboratoryTransactionSDJPaService implements LaboratoryTransactionService {
    private LaboratoryTransactionRepository laboratoryTransactionRepository;
    private LabTxnCommandToLabTxn labTxnCommandToLabTxn;

    public LaboratoryTransactionSDJPaService(LaboratoryTransactionRepository laboratoryTransactionRepository,
                                             LabTxnCommandToLabTxn labTxnCommandToLabTxn) {
        this.laboratoryTransactionRepository = laboratoryTransactionRepository;
        this.labTxnCommandToLabTxn = labTxnCommandToLabTxn;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<LaboratoryTransaction> findAll() {
        Set<LaboratoryTransaction> laboratoryTransactions = new HashSet<>();
        laboratoryTransactionRepository.findAll().forEach(laboratoryTransactions::add);
        return laboratoryTransactions;
    }

    @Override
    public LaboratoryTransaction findByID(Long aLong) {
        return laboratoryTransactionRepository.findById(aLong).get();
    }

    @Override
    public LaboratoryTransaction add(LaboratoryTransaction object) {
        return laboratoryTransactionRepository.save(object);
    }

    @Override
    public LaboratoryTransaction add(LaboratoryTransactionCommand object) {
        LaboratoryTransaction lab = labTxnCommandToLabTxn.convert(object);
        return laboratoryTransactionRepository.save(lab);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(LaboratoryTransaction object) {
        laboratoryTransactionRepository.delete(object);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteById(Long aLong) {
        laboratoryTransactionRepository.deleteById(aLong);
    }

    @Override
    public void addCommand(LaboratoryTransaction object) {

    }
}
```

This is a sample json object

{
"patientId" : 197,
"userId" : 1,
"dateTransaction" : "2017-10-25",
"comment" : "double wahala",
"discount" : 25,
"presentingComplaints" : [],
"provisionalDiagnosis" : [],
"laboratoryTransactionDetailCommands" : [{
"laboratoryInvestigationId" : 23,
"servicePriceCodeCommand" : {
"id" : 13,
"servicePrice" : "",
"discountPrice" : "",
"tax" : ""
},
"userDiscount" : 23,
"useDiscountPrice" : 1,
"comment" : "Aruma Oteh",
"timeOfTransaction" : "",
"dateOfTransaction" : "",

```
    "packageId" : "",
    "experimentReadingCommands" :[]
}],
"referralId" : 1
```

}

Every thing works fine, except that the lab transaction details (with foreign key transaction detail id) do not persist in the db with the transaction id. I will appreciate any help. Thanks